# How do automatically discard duplicate messages in activemq

Tags: java, activemq-classic

I have a configuration in my activemq broker to not forward the messages to **.DLQ** queue.

```
       <destinationPolicy>
            <policyMap>
              <policyEntries>
              <policyEntry queue=">">
                <!-- 
                    Tell the dead letter strategy not to process expired messages
                    so that they will just be discarded instead of being sent to
                    the DLQ 
                -->
                    <deadLetterStrategy>
                        <sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />
                    </deadLetterStrategy>
                </policyEntry>
              </policyEntries>
            </policyMap>
        </destinationPolicy>
```

But still am getting the messages to store in **.DLQ** queue.
[image]

When I tried to view the messages those stored in **.DLQ** I can see some additional attributes shows the below reason

`dlqDeliveryFailureCause java.lang.Throwable: duplicate from store for queue://xxxxxx`

Is there any way to discard the duplicate message to not send to **.DLQ** queue in **activemq**.

Comment: You've added the `activemq-artemis` tag to your question, but the question appears to be only about ActiveMQ "Classic". Can you clarify how ActiveMQ Artemis is involved here?

Answer (score 0):

Duplicate from store messages can occur when there is high contention on the queue-- usually from a large number of consumers with high prefetch and page size on the queue.

The broker is paging in messages as fast as possible for each consumer. The queue's dupe detection then filters these dupes out and pushes a copy to the DLQ as a way to inform you that you have contention.

I added a new config flag in (5.17.x) that disables the messages from going to the DLQ and instead adds a counter so you are able to observe when this occurs.

set: sendDuplicateFromStoreToDLQ="false"

In 5.18.x, "false" will be the default value.

The "fix" is to lower the contention on the queue by tuning the consumer count + prefetch + pageSize settings settings so this occurs less frequently -- or (ideally) not at all